# Create a file in the parent directory in OCaml?

Tags: file, ocaml

This is my current directory structure

```
/project
   /code (source code)
   /build (contains the .exe)
```

Part of source code:

```
let () =
  let oc = open_out file in    (* create or truncate file, return channel *)
  fprintf oc "%s\n" message;   (* write something *)   
  close_out oc;
```

If I run .exe in the /build sub-directory, it will create the output file in the /build. But I want to create a new directory named result and create the output file under it.

new directory structure:

```
/project
  /code (source code)
  /build (contains the .exe)
  /result (contains the output file)
```

How to create a new directory under the parent directory and write files into it using OCaml? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create by hand the result directory, you can than replace your filename with :

```
let oc = open_out ("../result/"^file) in
...
```

If you need to create the directory from your program,  you can use `Unix.mkdir "../result"`. Be sure to wrap it in a `try ... with Unix.Error -> ...` to handle the case where the directory already exists

Comment: You can use [`Unix.mkdir`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALmkdir) `"../result"` if you want to create the directory from OCaml.  Be sure to wrap it in a [`try ... with Unix.Error...`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#EXCEPTIONUnix_error) to handle the case where the directory already exists!

Comment: @ChriS You right, i did not mention it because i was  unsure about the behaviour of Unix functionnalities with windows. But apparently it works fine. I added this to my answer :)